# Any ramifications of wearing a digital watch instead of an analog one?

Tags: professionalism

I notice that my male colleagues all wear analog watches (with mechanical hands). I find digital ones more practical. Are there any professional ramifications on wearing a digital watch? Thanks!

Comment: No need to make fun of this. While it's subtle, there is a difference between showing up with an iWatch, a Rolex, a fitbit, or one of these beauties http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/171786414919?lpid=82&chn=ps or http://www.ebay.com/itm/Hot-Sale-Fashion-Women-Men-Unisex-Blue-LED-Digital-Date-Quartz-Wrist-Watch-KAE/190685132555?_trksid=p2141725.c100338.m3726&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20141212152715%26meid%3D44c42f161d3248a99150ec9c942fa70f%26pid%3D100338%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D30%26sd%3D171786414919

Comment: I disagree with the down-vote. I have, in fact, up-voted it. This is an example of someone being aware of his environment (or her) and wanting to 'fit in', or at least not be at a loss for (promotion, recognition, etc) for something which should not matter, but does more often than not and is asking how to work through it.

Comment: Folks if you are wondering whether to comment, take care to read [this meta post about Keeping the Workplace Professional](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2979/2322) and ensure you are respecting those posters here. If you can't say anything nice, don't say anything at all. Thanks!

Comment: @enderland My apologies for the lapse of judgement. When I posted the comment, it felt like an obvious troll question. (I imagined more questions coming up like, "Everyone else wears a beard, should I shave?" "Everyone else wears spectacles with black frame, should I use one with a brown frame?", etc.), but after reading the answers I realize it was a mistake on my part. Also, even if it was a troll question, feeding the troll was a bad idea.

Comment: If you want to stand out, use neither an analog watch nor a digital watch. Use a pocket watch. If I see someone checking time with his pocket watch then I know he means business.

Comment: In this day, why would anyone wear a watch?  I haven't owned one since the 70s - one that I got, along with a typewriter, as high school graduation presents.

Comment: I suspect that if anyone is going to judge you on this, it will be whether you wear something that is essentially functional jewelry/status-symbol, a $5.95 Helllo Kitty disposable, or something in the middle. Digital vs analog won't signify compared to price. Of course there's no agreement about whether most-expensive means sophisticated or foolish, so i'd suggest you just avoid anything that looks like it came from a cereal box... unless you can convince people you're wearing it as a deliberate statement. (I wear a watch because it's the nicest option for a medical alert.)

Comment: I'm curious why you think it could be an issue.

Comment: A fact-based comment: If you work near fairly strong magnets, I have discovered that analog watches experience more time-keeping issues owing to problems with magnetization of the movement pieces. A late or stopped watch helps nobody even if it is a looker and is the exact reason I reverted to wearing digital watches even though I personally prefer analog.

Comment: Unless it's an [expensive watch](http://destads.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/047.png) (more than a few thousand dollars) I doubt anyone will notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. Do you work in a "blue collar" shop? Older co-workers (40's+)? We grew up (I'm 51) learning how to "tell time" the "old fashioned way" where it is truly easier for me to tell the general time by the hands' positioning on the dial.

(This next paragraph is partly tongue in cheek, partly exasperation, and partly truth)

Kid's these days! Sheesh. Digital this, computer that, automatic the other. I don't have statistics at hand, but I can safely presume, at least in the world in which I live (Northern Virginia, USA) that the twenty-somethings, millennial, whatever you may, were never taught to tell time. They read the numbers on the digital clock and mentally process that into the time of day.

So, you might be seeing proof of generational gap.

On the other hand ...

If you are working in a less "blue collar" shop, perhaps even high end, maybe finance, or well, how do I put this. I am a contractor for a very large multinational firm. I am contracted by my company to the government in a job I cannot talk about. Those of us who work at the customer site are the "worker bees". Then we have our divisional corporate offices. People who work there, at the headquarters buildings are this set of people. They may be doing the exact job as I am, but they are, by dint of where they work, more concerned with ... lets say image. Dress nicer. Be ready to be seen by the upper management.

OK, now we are with the people who care less about what they learned, and more about image. You'll see nicer accessories. Silk ties, vice cotton or whatever (I don't wear one.) I'll wear a wedding ring, they'll wear maybe class rings as well. My watch would be an analog Timex ($20-30). They might wear a nicer watch (I don't know brands, but $100ish). They might also consider wearing analog so as not to "look" like a ... well ... kid. Millennial. Whatever.

Then you have the offices where looks **matter**. That person will know exactly what he wants to wear, and buy it. $1000 or $10,000. It will be stylish, expensive and present exactly the look he wants to present. This will be your Senior VP, or CEO.

Bringing it back down and around to you. If everyone is wearing analog, is everyone slightly older than you? If so, don't worry, it's what they know. Do you want to be comfortable, buy and wear what you know. Do you want to completely 'fit in'? Buy and wear (and learn to use) what everyone else does.

Does it *really really* matter? Probably not. You're not going to get fired for wearing the wrong *watch*. (Unless there are policies, etc)

**Now for concrete advice.**
Find a watch that fits well on your wrist, both in looks and feel; one that is not dirt cheap, but is a minor percentage of your monthly salary. Find one that fits these criteria and has *both* analog dials and a digital display. read what is comfortable for you and know you have done your best to fit in with them as well.

Comment: Or declare you don't care, wear something that you think looks good,  and let those with opinions cope.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as it touches on differences in occupation and colleagues' backgrounds.

Answer (score 4):

While this is a minor issue, it's all a part of how you present yourself at the workplace. It matters as much or as little as how you dress or what you eat, etc and as such has some impact on how people perceive you. There is a subtle difference between people wearing analog watch, digital watch, a smart watch, or a fitbit. A rolex comes across differently than an iWatch.

There is no right or wrong, just do what best reflects who you actually are and avoid being inconsistent. Don't wear a smart watch that you can't operate or wear a fitbit and show up with super sized McDonalds meal for lunch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb, and answer this with a very blatant **no**. There are no ramifications to be had from wearing a digital watch, as opposed to a mechanical watch.

It wouldn't hurt to ask though. It could be a social thing you might want to be part of.

Comment: It will hurt to ask. Wearing the "wrong" watch might hurt in some places (but not in many), but in those places showing that you cannot even decide for yourself which watch to wear will hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Wearing a watch in general does have ramifications - you are perceived as more professional and caring about time (even though the watchless could use their phones) **and** you look at your phone less, giving people less opportunities to think you're checking for messages when it was just a time check.

But the way that watch displays time to you is purely a matter of taste. Some will judge you for it, as they will judge for your shoes or your haircut. Don't sweat it though, it's really not a big deal at all.